# BizTalk subscription order of evaluation

Tags: biztalk

I'd like to subscribe to exceptions, while leaving existing code in place to handle all other cases. XSLT applies tests in order of complexity. Is the behavior of subscriptions that 'conflict' defined?

It should be possible using service windows, but I'd like a more robust solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no order that subscriptions are applied in BizTalk, nor is there a conflict in subscriptions.    If more than one subscription matches the message, both will get the message and process it.

If you don't want the existing subscription to process those messages, you need to add a `AND {propertyname} <> {value}` to the existing subscription.